# How can I recognize mould in the soil of potted plants?

Tags: containers, bonsai, mold

1. Is this mould on my bonsai's soil?

[image]

2. If it is mould, how can I treat it?
3. How can I recognise mould in potted plants in general?

Comment: Salt deposits from tap water for sure so use distilled water that you purchase.  Is this soil potting soil or is it garden soil?  Make sure this little trunk is OUT OF THE SOIL, GRAVEL, SAND, MOSS so that it can stay dry.  This moisture on the bottom of your truck spells death.  A slow but sure death.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you're watering with tapwater and have done so for a while, some of this white deposit might be salts from the water; however, in reference to your other query, the salt deposits would have been present whilst the plant was in your office, and it seems you've only noticed it recently. The photograph, with close inspection, does show there is some fungal growth. Don't water for a while, and make sure its somewhere warm (not close to a heat source though, just a warm room) and the  mould should dry up and disappear. In connection with your other query on  this plant, this has grown because you've continued to water in the same way as you did in your office, but its clear that the temperature and humidity in  your home is different - cooler temperature, likely higher humidity compared to the office.